# Convergent or divergent? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}$$
converge?

Comment: did you take the limit of the summand as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: It goes to $0$ -- see the answers below. The problem is that is goes to $0$ *too slowly*; roughly $\propto \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} &= \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n 
= \frac{1}{n+1}e^{-n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1}e^{-n\left(\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}
= \frac{1}{n+1}e^{-1+o\left(1\right)} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{-1}}{n}
\end{align*}$$
As the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-1}}{n}$ diverges, so does this one.

Answer (score 6):

We have

$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac1{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}\sim_\infty\frac{e^{-1}}{n}$$
and the harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac1n$ is divergent. Conclude using the asymptotic  comparison.